# how to get the updated UIImageView size (width and hight) when using UIPinchGestureRecognizer in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am add a UIImage in UIImageView. the i am apply UIPinchGestureRecognizer on UIImageView.
i want to find updated UIImageView.frame=(x,y,width,hight). please give suggestion

thanx.